# CLOSED Uncaught Error: [vuex] must call Vue.use(Vuex) before creating a store instance. CLOSED

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am using this pattern from [this example](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/tree/dev/examples/shopping-cart) .

I am also using `vue-cli`.

First everything works fine until I build the project using `yarn build` or `npm run build`.

I tried re-arranging the position of the store invocation but nothing positive is happening.

So I decided to completely remove the `Vuex` from my project, but freaking hell, the error was still there.

I removed:
 1. `Vuex` from `main.js`.
 2. Uninstall Vuex from node_modules
 3. Delete every possible store and vuex instance in the whole project.

Here's a short screen recording of what's happening. https://youtu.be/rHO9_LhZMQE

Anybody experiencing the same?

[image]

Comment: Click on one of the callstack items and view the exact line that is generating the error.

Comment: @Stephan-v actually I finally found what's causing this. Apparently `vueditor` one of the plugin that Im using has it's own implementation of vuex. What a pain.